# How to export the result from statsmodels test to CSV?

Tags: python, csv, statsmodels

I am just learning how to use the [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) (Python module) to perform such things as regression analysis, testing for normality and homogenous variance. I am working with several data sets (usually as CSV files) and would like to write a script to help me do this more efficiently. My data is just a set of numbers.

**Example of data**

```
column1, column2
2.80609,2.80609
2.39059,1.6697286666666666
3.6487540000000003,1.8243770000000001
1.8582885714285717,3.0046419047619044
2.587834,1.7252226666666666
...
```

Specifically, I would like to:

(1) Iterate a test over several files

(2) Save the result of each test to a new row in a new file

**An example of one of the tests I am using.**

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv") 

column1 = data['column1']
p_value = sm.stats.diagnostic.lilliefors(data, dist='norm', pvalmethod='approx')
```

**The float it exports look like this.**

```
(0.08557045418097009, 7.144631930303909e-50)
```

My adventures into if/else and boolean values resulted in this code that prints a text that would be nifty to have exported as well.

```
p_value = sm.stats.diagnostic.lilliefors(curvature_length, dist='norm', pvalmethod='approx')[1]
if p_value<0.05:
    print("Data is not normal distributed")
else:
    print("Data is normal distributed")
print(p_value)
```

Any tips & feedback on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what do you want to export again? the two floats into a line of a csv file?

Comment: Preferably 3 floats. But a solution for the two first were supplied by user @WurmD below. As you can see in the last piece of code I posted it would be useful to export a print "Data is/is not normal distributed" based on one of the values and append this to as a new column. Any I could also do this separably using numpy and pandas but would be neat to include in this section of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write the two floats to CSV https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
```

cycle through the pairs of floats doing

```
        csvwriter.writerow([float1, float2])
```

Comment: Thx! I will accept the answer. This was very useful. But my implementation overwrote each line when I iterate it over several files using f-string. I changed 'w' to 'a' which appends each new row below the old. But this poses a problem. If I run the code several time, new rows are added that are copies of the previous ones. Any input on this would be helpful! :-)

Comment: make the first `with open(` call with 'w', and the rest 'a' :)

Comment: That may be possible but to clarify, each data file is called by an f-string. The first run may have "sample1, sample2", but the next round will have "sample1, sample2, sample3". More files will be added over time. I would prefer not have the poor researchers to go in and modify the script when I hand it over to save them time. :-)

Comment: I don't follow. If goal is "when re-running script, csv file is first deleted, and then repopulated", and in the script there are several `with open(` calls. Then if the first call in the script is with 'w' it will clear out the csv before writting, and the next calls be all with 'a', will append

Comment: New to Python lingo which may add to the confusion. I will only run the script one time for each session. When I try this with 'w' it only adds the last file in the f-string. When I try it with 'a' it appends even if there exists a previous entry. Makes sense?